# Como criar uma função create usando dados de tabelas com relação de n para n?

Tags: mvc

Acontece que a função create que o outro estagiário fez não funciona porque tem duas tabelas com relação de n-n e na função ele so esta a ir buscar dados e regista los numa. Só que não consigo achar forma de adicionar outra tabela ou usar a tabela relacional.

Este é o código da função create que ele deixou

```
' GET: DEF_DEFECT/Create
    Function Create() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function

    ' POST: DEF_DEFECT/Create
    'To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    'more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    <HttpPost()>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function create(<Bind(Include:="CODE_DEF,DESCRIPTION_DEF")> ByVal dEF_DEFECT As DEF_DEFECT) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.DEF_DEFECT.Add(dEF_DEFECT)
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End If
        Return View(dEF_DEFECT)
    End Function
```

Ele mandou buscar o `code_def` e `description_def` na tabela `def_defect` mas preciso que va buscar o `cod_process` da tabela `Pro_Process`.

Estas 2 tabelas, ao ser normalizadas deram origem á tabela `Process_Defect`
Será que alguém me pode dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri como solucionar.

Afinal o MVC é mesmo uma grande ferramenta de auxilio, mas para quem como eu está a começar acaba por ser um pouco confuso. Então, criei uma private sub para fazer update á base de dados e problema resolvido. :)

```
Private Sub UpdateDefectProcess(updateDefect As DEF_DEFECT, processSelected As String)
        'Dim selectedProcessHS = New HashSet(Of String)(processSelected)
        Dim selectedProcessHS = processSelected

        Dim defectProcess As IEnumerable(Of String) = New HashSet(Of String)(updateDefect.PRO_PROCESS.Select(Function(c) c.CODE_PRO))
        For Each c In db.PRO_PROCESS
            If selectedProcessHS.Contains(c.CODE_PRO.ToString()) Then
                updateDefect.PRO_PROCESS.Add(c)
            Else
                If defectProcess.Contains(c.CODE_PRO) Then
                    updateDefect.PRO_PROCESS.Remove(c)
                End If
            End If

        Next

    End Sub
```

E a funçao create ficou assim,

```
 ' GET: DEF_DEFECT/Create
    Function Create() As ActionResult
        PopProcessDropDownList()
        Return View()
    End Function

    ' POST: DEF_DEFECT/Create
    'To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    'more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    <HttpPost()>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function Create(<Bind(Include:="CODE_DEF,DESCRIPTION_DEF")> ByVal dEF_DEFECT As DEF_DEFECT) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.DEF_DEFECT.Add(dEF_DEFECT)

            Dim processSelected As String = Request.Form("ProcessesList").ToString()

            UpdateDefectProcess(dEF_DEFECT, processSelected)

            db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")

        End If
        Return View(dEF_DEFECT)
    End Function
```

Pode ser que ajude alguem que tenha o mesmo problema que tive